UML sequence diagrams: does creating a boundary automatically show it?
my colleagues and I are currently working on a university project about software engineering. At the moment, I am focusing on sequence diagrams and I have a few questions:
Is there a standard for creating sequence diagrams, or can I proceed as long as the logic is sound?
In a sequence diagram, does creating a Boundary (corresponding to a screen of the software) automatically imply its display?
I have been following the logic where I create a Boundary and then show it, because in some cases the Boundary differs based on the type of user or certain controls.
So, to summarize:

I create the boundary
I perform the necessary checks, based on which the boundary is populated, possibly in different ways
Once the checks are completed, performed with possible alt or opt, I show the boundary with a show() function that starts from the control.

Is the logic correct?

There is indeed a standard for creating UML diagrams and a very precise semantic, in the UML specifications. You can freely download it from OMG's website.
But the «Entity», «Boundary», «Control» stereotypes are not part of the current version of the specifications. It's nevertheless common stereotypes to define objects corresponding to a use-case analysis.
Since the standard doesn't say anything, you cannot expect anything. It is up to you to define the behavior of classifiers having the Boundary stereotype, and nothing prevents you to specify that it appears as soon as it is created. You would typically define the behaviors (e.g. the constructor) in a class diagram.
You may also mimic some behaviors closer to common windowing system, with creation and display in two phases. Last but not least, you could be interested to define several boundaries that are specialization of a more general boundary. You may then just create the right boundary.

You might note that using thiose stereotypes requires a profile which defines their semantics. Not sure whether such a profile already exists. Sparx EA uses some internal profile.
